# How to integrate Mantis with TestLink

Tags: xampp, mantis, testlink

OS: Windows 10

I have installed TestLink(testlink-1.9.15) and Mantis(mantisbt-1.3.3) on XAMPP successfully. Both of them can be launched in browser separately.

I want to integrate Mantis with TestLink. To do this I followed the doc "tl-bts-howto.pdf" which is located at \testlink\docs folder. In that PDF I found the following lines to configure Mantis in TestLink:

Step 2 – Test Link – Configure Mantis interface

Edit file /cfg/mantis.cfg.php

But, unfortunately I did not find any file named "mantis.cfg.php" in cfg folder of TestLink.

What can I do? Is there any way to configure/integrate Mantis with TestLink?

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite: Successful installation of XAMPP

1. Install and configure TestLink and Mantis on XAMPP
2. Browse TestLink on a browser and log in (In my case it was http://localhost:8077/testlink/ )
3. Click "Issue Tracker Management" link at the left
4. Click Create button -> Enter a Issue Tracker name as your choice (I inputted as "mantis - (Interface:db)")
5. Select "mantis (Interface: db) from the Type drop down and enter the text in Configuration text area mentioned in screenshot attached herewith.
6. Lastly click Save button to save

Note: In the above configuration text, be specific for individual information. It may vary person to person.

You can get the configuration example by clicking "Show configuration example" link

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mantis.cfg.php is not part of Mantis. You can see this in the testlink source.

Comment: Yes, I searched mantis.cfg.php in TestLink source. But I did not find it in TestLink source. That is the problem I mentioned in my question.